# Godot cannot export to android Could not find keystore, unable to export, how to fix?

Tags: godot

Keystore create by the docs of godot. Video of export [video](https://youtu.be/8HFCUhLwQcg) if erase all still this error. Windows 10, Godot stable 3.3.2, default version

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you click "Export Project" Godot opens a "Save File" dialog where you choose the location for the apk or aab file. In that dialog, in the bottom left corner, there is a check box that says "Export With Debug".

If you select "Export With Debug", Godot will make a debug export. The debug export - as you would expect - uses the debug keystore. That is the keystore you have configured.

However, since didn't select "Export With Debug", Godot is trying to make a release export. The release export - surprise - uses the release keystore, which you need to create and configure. And given you haven't done that, Godot can't find the keystore.

So, either make a debug export by selecting "Export With Debug". Or create a new keystore and configure it for release.